# Datepicker show tomorrows date with 8 am by default in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i am trying to  get tomorrow date with 8 am by default in my datetimepicker input box 
so far i have those code..its working  but i  have added it that functionality separately instead of that can any one tell me how can i add it in side my `$(".reopenTicket").datetimepicker({` function

Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
echo $this->inlineScript()->appendScript(<<<EOS
    $(".reopenTicket").datetimepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/themes/bas/icons/fatcow/16x16/calendar.png",
        dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        buttonImageOnly: true, 
        controlType: 'select',
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        oneLine : true
    });
    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date(); 
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
    tomorrow.setHours(8);
    tomorrow.setMinutes(0);
    $(".reopenTicket").datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(tomorrow));
EOS
);
?>
```

Here is my input box to display that date

```
<?php
        echo $this->form->reopenTicket;
        echo $this->form->ticketId; 
    ?>
```

Can anyone help me with it

Thanks in advance.